# Why is ', ' translated to '%2C+'?

Tags: javascript, decodeuricomponent

I am working on a project using Node.js v21.7.1, from a MariaDB database I query first name and surname then pass these back to the client.

In my SQL I use:

```
CONCAT(`t2`.`vcSurName`, ',', `t2`.`vcFirstName`) AS vcName
```

My client receives this and adds it to a 'SELECT' HTML tag, I can see the name is displayed correctly, for example 'Platten, Simon' is shown, this is now part of a form which when submitted, I can see that the server receives the name as:

```
'Platten%2C+Simon'
```

On the server I have used:

```
var strUserName = decodeURIComponent(objFields['biUID']);
```

I then split the name into an array:

```
var aryName = strUserName.split(', ');
```

This is where is goes wrong, decodeURIComponent only translates the %2C back to a comma, but the content of aryName now contains:

```
[Platten,+Simon]
```

What do I need to do because the + is the result of encoding the space but it doesn't get decoded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decodeURIComponent()` only handles the percentage-encoded parts of the string. Decoding the `+` character needs to be done separately.

See also the [Decoding query parameters from a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent#decoding_query_parameters_from_a_url) chapter of MDN's `decodeURIComponent()` article, where it suggests the following code:

```js
function decodeQueryParam(p) {
  return decodeURIComponent(p.replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

decodeQueryParam("search+query%20%28correct%29");
// 'search query (correct)'
```

Comment: Thank you, ins't that a bit strange and daft, that there is something that encodes the data but in order to decode it you have to resort to something more than just a call to the decode routine?

Comment: @SPlatten The issue here is that the _proper_ encoding of the space, from the point of view of `decodeURIComponent()` is `%20`, not `+`. The notion of using `+` for space when encoding HTML form data is technically an older standard, and it's too late to change it. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type

Comment: I didn't add he +, so what did?

Comment: @SPlatten If you're using a normal HTML form and POSTing it, the data is by default encoded as the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type, which uses both percentage encoding and plus-as-space. As such, it's the browser itself that adds the plus. As with a lot of web development, this is a case of "The original design was questionable, but we can't fix it without accidentally breaking a lot of existing websites.".

Comment: the browser in this case is Chrome version 123.0.6312.86